# Python 3: Flatten Dictionary including lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, flatten

Is there an elegant way to achieve this in python 3? It is supposed to flatten the dictionary, while treating list indices like keys and thus including them in the flattening.

in:

```
{
  "a": 1,
  "b": {
    "c": 2
  },
  "d": [3,4],
  "e": [
    {
      "f": 5
    },
    {
      "g": 6
    }
  ]
}
```

out:

```
{
  "a": 1,
  "b.c": 2,
  "d.0": 3,
  "d.1": 4,
  "e.0.f": 5,
  "e.1.g": 6
}
```

Background:

- We are looking for a way to merge nested dictionaries containing lists
- The available merge tools seem to always merge lists with either an append strategy or with a replace strategy
- We however need to merge dicts that are inside lists (as in the example). E.g., the first dict in the list should be merged with the first dict in the list
- The current approach is to chain like this: `flatten -> merge -> unflatten`. The question was only about the flatten piece. We have since seen that the unflatten is trickier
- Optimally, we use already existing robust libraries

Comment: Please show your work and ask about the specific part that's tripping you up. These are worth a read: [Asking about homework](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/334823/6030926) and [Open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6166)

Comment: Edited with more background @picobit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possibiliy would be to make use of the [flatten-json](https://pypi.org/project/flatten-json/) library.

It provides a flatten, unflatten and unflatten_list function.

In your usecase the flatten und unflatten_list functions are needed.

```
from flatten_json import flatten, unflatten_list

d = {
  "a": 1,
  "b": {
    "c": 2
  },
  "d": [3,4],
  "e": [
    {
      "f": 5
    },
    {
      "g": 6
    }
  ]
}

desired_result = {
  "a": 1,
  "b.c": 2,
  "d.0": 3,
  "d.1": 4,
  "e.0.f": 5,
  "e.1.g": 6
}


d_flat = flatten(d, separator=".")
print(d_flat == desired_result)  # True

d_unflat = unflatten_list(d_flat, separator=".")
print(d == d_unflat)  # True
```

Answer (score 1):

```
d= {
  "a": 1,
  "b": {
     "c": 2
   },
  "d": [3,4],
   "e": [
    {
       "f": 5
     },
     {
       "g": 6
     }
   ]
 }
result={}
def f(d,s=''):
     if type(d)==dict:
        for k,v in d.items():
            f(v,s=s+k+'.')
    elif type(d)==list:
        for i,v in enumerate(d):
            f(v,s=s+str(i)+'.')
    else:
        result[s[:-1]]=d
f(d)
print(result)
```